# Otimização com GCC

Tags: c, otimização, gcc, compiladores

Recentemente estive pensando se é possível o compilador com alguma *flag* de otimização, evitar a copia de dois *arrays* para a seção `.rodata`? Assim, os endereços de memória seriam iguais, exemplo

```
const char str[7] = "string";

const char str1[7] = "string";


int printf(const char *format, ...);

int main(void) {

     if(str == str1) 
         printf("Endereços de memória iguais");

     return 0;

}
```

Então neste exemplo acima, será que é possível de alguma forma o compilador usar os mesmos endereços de memória?

---

EDIT:

Não faz muito sentido mesmo não, kkkk, era só questão de curiosidade mesmo, tentei ver algumas *flags* de otimização, mas sem sucesso.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {

     char *str1 = "string";
     char *str2 = "string";

     if(str == str2) puts("Igual");
}
```

No exemplo acima, o compilador coloca a *string* literal do ponteiro `str1` na seção `.rodata` e utiliza a mesma *string*, ou seja o mesmo endereço pra o ponteiro `str2`. Por isso quis saber, se da pra simular isso fazendo com *array*. Li a Manpage do GCC, mas não achei nada relevante nesse sentido, mas de qualquer forma muito obrigado pela sua resposta.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível, se bem que este código não parece fazer muito sentido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char str[7] = "string";
    const char *str1 = str;
    if(str == str1) printf("Endereços de memória iguais");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jrvmGc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vomkmmep-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Interning.c).

Eu sei que esperava outra resposta, mas outra não faz sentido. Em C se você quer uma otimização, otimize, não espere o compilador fazer por você.

Comment: A standard permite que duas string literals de mesmo conteúdo tenham o mesmo espaço de armazenamento e, portanto, o mesmo endereço. Depois eu procuro pra fazer uma resposta (ou faça tu mesmo se quiser). E.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/qiGPT9

Comment: Permitir não é garantir, eu prefiro o garantido.

Comment: Achei que a pergunta do OP era sobre otimizações, coisa que não é "garantida" e sim "possível."

Comment: Vlw Mário e Maniero. Conseguir usando a flag -fmerge-all-constants. Na realidade o compilador tenta evitar duplicar as strings, desde que sejam constantes e idênticas, porém não é garantido que o compilador sempre faça isso.